# Node.JS logging very messy

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm using [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) for logging in node.js applications. It's a great tool but due to the async nature of node.js, log entries of a particular function in log files are scattered around and mixed with other. This makes analysis of the log very difficult, especially when you're in a loop of calling same function multiple times.

For example,

```
function query(id, callback) {
    logger.verbose('start', id); 
    db.query({id:id}, callback)
}

var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
for(var i = ids.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
    query(ids[i], function(err, result) {
        if(err) logger.error('db error', id, err);
        else logger.verbose('db result', id, result); 
        callback(); 
    }
}
```

While first entry will certainly be

```
start 5
```

All subsequent log entries' appearance will become unpredictable, so tracing error occurred for a specific query is very hard.

My questions here are:

- What's the best practice to make a same function call's log entries more traceable.
- If grouping all log entries for same function call is not possible, is there any known tools/practices to help analysis of this messy log?

Comment: Find a unique id associated with one particular query, include that in all relevant log statements and then grep your log to just get all the log statements with that id in it.

Comment: I see your point, but that unique id is not always available.

Comment: Well, that's how you associate a set of log entries that belong to one particular transaction in a log that has lots of other things going on in it.  You may have to pass some extra arguments around in your code for debugging purposes in order to solve that problem.  In your case, you need to "engineer" the logging to be useful.  That may mean passing some more info into places where you can use it for your logging.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's probably what I'm doing now. I log caller info and id when available, but still feel this is not enough. I'm just guessing there has to be some better solution.

Comment: You either have to put identifying info into each line of the log so you can correlate the appropriate lines, use separate log files for separate things or turn off all other logging so that only the things you want to see are in your log during your specific investigation.  It is not uncommon to have to do some work to analyze logs to get them to tell you meaningful things.  I've been in numerous situations where people wrote special scripts to pull desired information from logs.